Max number of walks to a goal vertex, each with different starting vertex
I want to solve the following problem:
Given an undirected graph $G$ with positive integer weights, find maximum number of walks (each with different starting vertices) that ends at some specified vertex $v$, and the total number of times one travels through an edge in all these walks can't exceed the edge's weight. The time bound is $O(m^2)$, where $m$ is number of edges of $G$.
For example, if an edge has weight 2, then at most 2 different walks can use it as part of the walk. If a walk use this edge twice, then no other walks can use it. We can view it as decreasing the edge's weight by 1 every time one uses this edge in a walk. We keep finding walks and decrease the edges' weights, starting from a new (we can pick) starting vertex in a new walk, until there's no walk from any vertex to the specified end vertex.
My attempt:
The problem was originally phrased in terms of bridges and islands, so formalizing it into a graph problem is already a part of my attempt. One other idea I have is that all walks must just be simple paths, since cycles are useless to what we want to do. The problem feels somewhat like the max flow problem (although we don't have same starting vertex in this problem, and the graph is undirected rather than directed), but I'm not sure how exactly to relate them.

I'd suggest that you approach this problem by working out from the common ending vertex, v. Summing the weights of that vertex's edges tells you the maximum number of walks it will support. If you turn the problem around this way then you do have the same starting vertex and perhaps max flow can help you.

You are right that maximum flow problem can be helpful here.
Converting undirected graph into directed is pretty simple for network flow. Just replace every edge $\{\,u, v\,\}$ by two arcs $(u, v)$ and $(v, u)$.
Note that augmenting paths are not the same as the paths which increase the answer. Augmenting paths may use an edge more times than the edge weight, passing it in both directions. However two passes in opposite directions discard each other. So flow gives you the number of paths, not paths themselves. Though paths may be restored afterwards.
And the condition that you need to use different vertices as a starting vertex doesn't break the idea. Just use end vertex $v$ as sink and a new vertex $s$ as source. Then for each vertex $u \in V(G) \setminus \{\,v\,\}$ add an arc $(s, u)$ of weight $1$. Thus you switch from searching for paths starting with pairwise distinct vertices to searching for paths starting with $s$.
Note that there are at most $n - 1$ paths, so network flow capacity is at most $n - 1$ and can be found in time $\mathrm O(n(m + n))$. Supposing for simplicity that the graph is connected, we conclude that $m \ge n - 1$ and the running time is $\mathrm O(nm) = \mathrm O(m^2)$ as desired.
